# How do I go about changing the color of a single specific SliderTextInputs in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885633/change-color-of-slider-text-input-widget-in-shiny-r) question and response, I'm trying to adjust the color of a specific sliderTextInput while leaving another one untouched in R Shiny by applying CCS to the input. The answer to that question mentions that it should work by applying the css properties to the class children of the respective input ID. However, this is where i struggle. I'm not familiar with HTML syntax and my guess of `mySliderText1 .irs--shiny .irs-bar` seems to be incorrect. What's the correct syntax or how else would I get this to work?
Thanks in advance!

Below is an expanded MWE based on the answer by gdevaux:

````
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
    .irs--shiny .irs-bar {
      background: blueviolet;
      border-top: 1px solid blueviolet;
      border-bottom: 1px solid blueviolet;
    }
    .irs--shiny .irs-to, .irs--shiny .irs-from {
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }
    .irs--shiny .irs-handle {
      border: 1px solid #c41818;
      background-color: #c41818;
    }")),
  
  
  br(),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "mySliderText",
    label = "Month range slider:",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name[c(4, 7)]
  ),
  br(),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "mySliderText1",
    label = "Month range slider 1:",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name[c(1, 5)]
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Answer (score 3):

Just as a reference. If you want to apply your CSS based on the `inputId` of the `sliderTextInput` then one option would be to use the [next sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator). The latter is necessary as the `inputId` is only added to the slider's `label` (plus a suffix `-label`) not the single elements which make up the slider.

```r
library("shinyWidgets")
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
    #mySliderText1-label + .irs--shiny .irs-bar {
      background: blueviolet;
      border-top: 1px solid blueviolet;
      border-bottom: 1px solid blueviolet;
    }
    #mySliderText1-label + .irs--shiny .irs-to, 
      #mySliderText1-label + .irs--shiny .irs-from {
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }
    #mySliderText1-label + .irs--shiny .irs-handle {
      border: 1px solid #c41818;
      background-color: #c41818;
    }")),
  br(),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "mySliderText",
    label = "Month range slider:",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name[c(4, 7)]
  ),
  br(),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "mySliderText1",
    label = "Month range slider 1:",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name[c(1, 5)]
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8961
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input and in depth explanation. Even though I applied SamRs solution, it's always great and helpful to see alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the html generated by your code, you'll see that the slider handle and labels are not children of the input item with the label `"mySliderText"`, but siblings. You could traverse the DOM looking for siblings, but I think the most practical way to resolve this is to just wrap the relevant slider input in a `<div>` with a particular class.

```r
div(id = "sliderdiv", sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "mySliderText",
    label = "Month range slider:",
    choices = month.name,
    selected = month.name[c(4, 7)]
))
```

Then apply the style only to children of that class:

```r
tags$style(HTML("
#sliderdiv .irs-bar {
    background: blueviolet;
    border-top: 1px solid blueviolet;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blueviolet;
}
#sliderdiv .irs-from, #sliderdiv .irs-to {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
#sliderdiv .irs-handle {
    border: 1px solid #c41818;
    background-color: #c41818;
}"))
```

Output:

[image]

#### Full code

```r
library("shinyWidgets")
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML("
    #sliderdiv .irs-bar {
      background: blueviolet;
      border-top: 1px solid blueviolet;
      border-bottom: 1px solid blueviolet;
    }
    #sliderdiv .irs-from, #sliderdiv .irs-to {
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }
    #sliderdiv .irs-handle {
      border: 1px solid #c41818;
      background-color: #c41818;
    }")),
    br(),
    div(id = "sliderdiv", sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "mySliderText",
        label = "Month range slider:",
        choices = month.name,
        selected = month.name[c(4, 7)]
    )),
    br(),
    sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "mySliderText1",
        label = "Month range slider 1:",
        choices = month.name,
        selected = month.name[c(1, 5)]
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your in depth explanation and adjustments to the code. I got it to work perfectly with my code and was able to adjust all relevant sliders to my needs.